# Regex to find a string between two special known characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse messages transmited over TCP for my own network protocol using regex without success.

My commands start with ! followed by COMMAND_NAME and a list of arguments in the format or ARGUMENT_NAME=ARGUMENT_VALUE enclosed in <>

for example:

```
!LOGIN?<USERNAME='user'><PASSWORD='password'>;
```

my code :

```
public class CommandParser
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> arguments = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public CommandParser(string input)
    {
        Match commandMatch = Regex.Match(input, @"\!([^)]*)\&");

        if (commandMatch.Success)
        {
            CommandName = commandMatch.Groups[1].Value;
        }

        // Here we call Regex.Match.
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input,"(?<!\\S)<([a-z0-9]+)=(\'[a-z0-9]+\')>(?!\\S)",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        //
        foreach (Match argumentMatch in matches)
        {
            arguments.Add(
                argumentMatch.Groups[1].Value,
                argumentMatch.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }

    public string CommandName { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Arguments
    {
        get { return arguments; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public int ArgumentCount
    {
        get { return arguments.Count; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the command name, finding the first word after the "!" should be enough:

```
/\!\w*/g
```

To match the key/value pairs in groups, you could try something like:

```
(\w+)='([a-zA-Z_]*)'
```

An example of the above regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/kUJk5n/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `regex` here and avoid them unless that's a last option left. You could do this with simple `C#` logic.

```
string input = "!LOGIN?<USERNAME='user'><PASSWORD='password'>";
string command = input.Substring(1, input.IndexOf('?') - 1);
Console.WriteLine($"command: {command}");
var parameters = input
                    .Replace($"!{command}?", string.Empty)
                    .Replace("<", "")
                    .Split(">".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string[] kvpair;
foreach(var kv in parameters) {
    kvpair = kv.Split('=');
    Console.WriteLine($"pname: {kvpair[0]}, pvalue: {kvpair[1]}");
}
```

Output:

```
command: LOGIN
pname: USERNAME, pvalue: 'user'
pname: PASSWORD, pvalue: 'password'
```